# I cant use https on domain name linked to ec2 instance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-route53

I am using AWS for all of this. I have a registered domain name and a static ip address linked to an ec2 instance. I can connect to the server by using http:// in a browser but i get an error connecting using https://. The error is: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. The ec2 instance is set up with a security group that has port 443 enabled on incoming and all traffic outgoing. [image: HTTPS setup] Am I missing something? Do I HAVE to use an elastic load balancer with an https listener on it or is there a way to get this to work how I have it now?

EDIT: I also have a public certificate issued to my domain via aws certificate manager. The CNAME is linked to the domain via route 53.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a self signed cert and then add it to your Static website in AWS .There are settings in AWS console to make it a https site .Then import that cert in your browser , so when browser will call your Website it will present a cert , when both certs match SSL handshake will happen. It has nothing to do with ELB.

Comment: I went into the certificate manager in AWS console and have a public certificate in issued status for my domain.  The CNAME is linked to the domain via route 53. Is this not the same thing as an ssl certificate because everything I read implies that it is the same.

Comment: Then you can try importing that public cert in your browser and then I believe you will be through.

Comment: im not sure what importing the certificate to the browser would do. plus, i just found this link that says it can only be used with select aws services which includes elastic load balancer. https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/